# Consequences of replacing a YouTube video on a Facebook post for the uploaded file

Tags: facebook

I have posted a YouTube video link on a Facebook post that by now has a large number of "likes" and "shares". I want to edit the post to remove the YouTube video link and instead upload the actual video file on it.

I own both the YouTube channel and the video file in question. In a nutshell I just want to get YouTube out of this equation so that people ONLY like the Facebook post instead of the YouTube video.

I know the "likes" and comments will still be there but what will happen with the "shares"?

Will they still show the YouTube video, will they show the now embedded video, or will the content now be unavailable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to do some experimentation and here are the answers to the questions:

Once you do a Facebook post with a link to a YouTube video and later edit it by removing the link and uploading a video file this is what happens to the "likes", "shares" and comments:

- The likes remain as they are.
- The comments remain as they are.
- The shares are unaffected, meaning that all the shares will still be linking to the original YouTube video.
- If someone shares the video and marks the option to "Include original post" then the share will now display the embedded video instead of the original link to YouTube.

I hope this information is useful for someone else.